# How to build a VS2015 solution that has a VS2010 configuration using MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I want to build a Visual Studio 2015 C++ solution from the command line using MSBuild. The complication is that I want to build a particular configuration of the solution, which uses the Visual Studio 2010 toolset (necessary because I am linking to a 3rd party library).

I have used MSBuild successfully in the past, but am unsure of which versions of MSBuild and vcvarsall.bat to use in this case.  Currently I am running:

"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
"\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild" mysolution2015.sln /p:Configuration="2010_Config" /p:useenv=true

but that gives error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'manifest:embed'

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the vcvarsall.bat from VS2015 ("\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat")
The chosen configuration will select the appropriate toolset (assuming you have both VS2015 and VS2010 installed).

You can then simply use msbuild has it will have been added to the path...

Comment: I still have a problem with this solution.  The VS2015 configurations of my VS2015 solution build correctly using msbuild. But the configuration that uses the VS2010 tools fails to build using msbuild (it builds ok from within the IDE).  Using msbuild, the errors include: `error C2039: 'gets': is not a member of 'std'` which suggests that the VS2015 compiler is running, not the VS2010 compiler.